# How can I prevent a callback from firing multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-animate

I've seen a couple of questions here regarding this, (including using when/promise solutions), but they didn't seem to work. Basically I'm animating multiple elements at once, and calling a function inside of the callback, but the function is being called multiple times - for each element being animated... Here's my code:

```
OBJCollection.css({
    'width': '0em',
    'height': '0em'
}).animate({
    'width': Screens.ImageW / 16 + 'em',
    'height': Screens.ImageH / 16 + 'em'
}, {
    duration: Screens.currentImageParent.data('LightboxFadeSpeedIn'),
    queue: false,
    step: function (now, fx) {
        componentScaler();
    },
    complete: function () {
        $Content.show('fade', Screens.currentImageParent.data('ContentFadeSpeedIn'));
        //calling function here
    }
});
```

I've attempted:

```
if (!OBJCollection.is(':animated')) { ... call function }
```

which didn't work. I've also attempted a solution with when, but that seemed to throw off my function call (which positions additional elements based on the final animated size of the OBJCollection). I'm not sure (since this was the first time I used when/promise), but is it firing the callback once after the first item is done animating and ignoring all others? It seems like that is what it's doing, but I'm looking for a solution that fires the callback when all items are done animating....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a promise object.

```
OBJCollection.css({
    'width': '0em',
    'height': '0em'
}).animate({
    'width': Screens.ImageW / 16 + 'em',
    'height': Screens.ImageH / 16 + 'em'
}, {
    duration: Screens.currentImageParent.data('LightboxFadeSpeedIn'),
    queue: false,
    step: function(now, fx) {
        componentScaler();
    }
}).promise().done(function() {
    $Content.show('fade', Screens.currentImageParent.data('ContentFadeSpeedIn'));
    //calling function here
});​
```

Comment: This works, and isn't throwing any errors, but like I said, I gave this a shot and it looks like it's firing the callback after the first animation is done, then ignoring the rest... I'm looking for a way to wait until all animations are complete.

Comment: what are "the rest"? the promise object will wait until all existing animations on the selected elements are done.

Comment: I'm reading through the DOCs for promise (sorry hadn't ever used it before) and it should run the function after all animations in the collection are complete... so I'm not exactly sure why it doesn't seem to be working correctly in my situation.

Comment: what is `componentScaler()`? is it doing any animations?

Comment: It's positioning additional elements based on the position/dimensions of the OBJCollection. I think promise is working, but I need to rewrite some of my other code, I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks! :)